# Is there a .NET 6.0 "Targeting Pack" installer separate from the SDK installer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to update a Visual Studio Project from a .NET 4.8 target to 6.0.

I have an up-to-date copy of Visual Studio (17.4.1) which is supposed to support 6.0, and I have the .NET 6.0.403 SDK installed. Based on a post I'd seen that later versions of the SDK could cause problems, I also tried using the 6.0.111 SDK, but that didn't help.

One difference I see when I look at what's installed on my system is that there's a "Targeting Pack" for 4.6.1, but not for 6.0 or 7.0.

[image: Add/Remove Programs screenshot]

I certainly don't remember doing anything special when I installed the 4.6.1 SDK to install a targeting pack, so it seems to have gotten installed automatically along with the SDK.

Why that's not happening now, I don't know. If 6.0 doesn't need a targeting pack, my copy of Visual Studio doesn't seem to understand that.

[image: Visual Studio "About" screenshot]

[image: Visual Studio target framework menu screenshot]

If there's a separate download for a .NET 6.0 targeting pack, I can't find it.

Do I perhaps have to delete the 4.6.1 targeting packs first, then maybe reinstall 6.0?

Is there some setting in Visual Studio setting that I'm missing?

Trying to edit my .csproj file to 6.0 manually, as I've seen suggested elsewhere, only resulted in an error when opening my project.

**Update:** I tried installing the Windows Hosting Bundle for 6.0.4 -- that didn't help.

Comment: You have the latest Visual Studio installed, which should include support for .NET 6 and 7. Have you tried running the migration assistant on your solution/project? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant

Comment: You can also check your installed runtimes and SDKs from the command line with `dotnet --list-runtimes` and `dotnet --list-sdks`.

Comment: @nullforce, I'm trying to use the upgrade-assistant now, and by default it's targeting 7.0, not 6.0. No matter what syntax I've tried so far, the `--msbuild-path` argument leads to the error "No MSBuild instance was found", even when I target the same 7.0 path I see in the analysis, not just the 6.0 path I'm trying.

Comment: @nullforce, both commands (I'd tried the --list-sdks command before myself) show that 6.0 is there.

Comment: For the upgrade assistant pass `-target-tfm-support LTS`. LTS will target .NET 6, Current (default) will target .NET 7.

Comment: @nullforce, I'll give that a try. I first decided to give the default with 7.0 a whirl just to see what happened, and I can't say I'm happy with all the assumptions made about my code.

Comment: If you already have SDK-style projects, all you need to do is change the `<TargetFramework>` entry to `net6.0` (and typically restart VS). The target runtime selection box is buggy.

Comment: @PMF, I tried this once before and just got a weird error (that I don't remember) when I tried to load the project, but I'd only closed the solution and reopened it after the manual change, without quitting VS. So I tried it again, and got no error, but my "Start" button was replaced with "Attach", and the config menus to the left of that (which normally read "Debug" and "Any CPU") were blank. I tried "v6.0" instead of "net6.0" (since I was replacing "v4.8"), but then I was just prompted to convert to 4.8 when I opened the project.

Comment: @kshetline Please show the .csproj file you have. There might be some other settings you need to update, but generally a manual edit of the file is the easiest way to convert it to net6.0.

Comment: @PMF: Here's the .csproj file: https://pastebin.com/jshcAkue

Answer (score 2):

Your project is still using the old format and uses both a packages.config and PackageReference. This is all quite a mess and will only lead to problems going forward. I think the easiest thing to do is to recreate your project from scratch. Create a new project (using any of the wizards), copy it over the existing file and then adjust it as needed. An SDK-style project file is much simpler than the old format, and in many cases only contains a handfull of package references.

Comment: I had used one of the basic wizards when I created this project just a couple on months ago, so I'm not sure where I went down the wrong path. The project is supposed to end up being a Windows service, debugged as a simple console app during development so it doesn't have to be installed as a service to be tested. Which wizard is appropriate for that? I looked over what's available, and nothing was an obvious choice, many seemed like they were designed for web deployment which is not what I want.

Comment: I think the easiest to use is "Console Application". Do not use "Console Application (.NET Framework)". It should ask you whether you want to use .NET 5.0, .NET 6.0 or .NET 7.0 or similar. The generated project file should only be about 10 lines.

Comment: Looking at the available wizards, there is only one choice for a C# Windows service, and it has the parenthetical (.NET Framework) descriptor, which is probably why I am where I am right now. Having not created a Windows service before, I'll have to find out if starting with plain-ol' "Console Application" will lead to something easily deployable as a Windows service.

Comment: @kshetline This may depend on the libraries used. It's probable that the API you use to register it as a service is different in .NET 6.0 or requires a special library.